# How to read the response from HttpResponse.sendredirect("url") method in filter in java?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, filter, saml

We have an application in which we want to validate the users using SSO. So in the java filter file we have redirected the URL to SSO url to validate, but I want to capture the response from that url. Is that possible? 
Currently I am using HttpResponse.sendredirect("url") this method doesn't return any data.
But the same url when tried using postman gives an html output that includes saml response.

Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send that redirect you don't do a request to that URL. You just add that redirect to the response and then the client will be redirected to that page.

If you want to do a request to that URL then you need a different logic. For example use apache http client or plain java code to do a request to that url and read the response.

Basically the client sending you request and you sending back the response is a different flow than you calling external URL and reading it's response. Unless just redirecting your client will work (but reading from your question I think that's not the case)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I got it worked. Tried it using filter chain and its working.